# difference between recursion and iteration?

Tags: recursion, iteration

Can someone please differentiate between iteration and recursion. Both are looking same to me..I know there will be a difference but don't know what . Please help me know the difference

Comment: have a look at a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2577042/2303366)

Answer (score 2):

**Recursion** is when a function/method is called from within the same function/method (directly or indirectly). This results in each successive call having a copy of its local variables on the stack (or wherever), and it needs to be 'unwound' at the end, by ending each of the functions/methods and coming back to the previous call.
Recursion often result in relatively short code, but use more memory when running (because all call levels accumulate on the stack)

**Iteration** is when the same code is executed multiple times, with changed values of some variables, maybe better approximations or whatever else. An iteration happens inside one level of function/method call and needs no unwinding.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this article will explain you: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~tp_200/lectureNotes/recursion.htm

Explain in pseudo code:

**recursion**

```
function f(x){
  do y;
   if(x<0){ return f(x-1) } else { return }
}
```

**iteration**

```
for(x in 1 to 10){
   do y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate by repeating a function.

Example, i is the iterator:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    function(input);
}
```

You recurse by using the function within itself.

Example:

```
function(input){
   if (input == outcome) {return;}
   else {function(input+1);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understood now.. Thanks once again